# Divisibility by 11 proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let n be a natural number, show that at least one of $(n^5)-1$, $(n^5)$ and $(n^5)+1$ is divisible by $11$.

I started by considering two cases:
$n$ is even. $n=2k$, so the three numbers become $32(k^5)-1$, $32k^5$, and $32(k^5)+1$
In mod $11$, it is equal to $-(k^5)-1$, $-k^5$, and $-(k^5)+1$

If $n$ is odd, $n^5=32k^5+80k^4+80k^3+40k^2+10k+1$
in mod $11$ it is $-k^5+3k^4+3k^3+7k^2-k+1$

And I want show that one of them eventually become $0$ in mod $11$, but it doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Why don't you evaluate all the fifth powers modulo $\;11\;$ ? That ends the problem at once...

Comment: Hint: $n^{11}\equiv n\pmod{11}$ by fermat's little theorem.  If $n$ were divisible by $11$ then we are done.  Otherwise then we have $(n^5)^2 \equiv 1\pmod{11}$ by a bit of factoring and dividing each side by $n$.

Comment: I am not with closing this question.

Answer (score 4):

If $11\mid n$, then $11\mid n^5$.

Otherwise, $11\mid n^{10}-1$ by Fermat's little theorem. And since $n^{10}-1=(n^5-1)(n^5+1)$, it follows from this that $11$ divides one of the numbers $n^5-1$ or $n^5+1$.

Comment: Nice hat.....!!